# Проблема установки Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, mod-rewrite

в логах вот так индекс загружается но когда обращается к ядру сбой загрузки происходит

```
[Sat Mar 05 16:51:43.843787 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 56608] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 91.192.136.218:46566] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Sat Mar 05 16:51:43.843822 2016] [core:error] [pid 56608] [client 91.192.136.218:46566] End of script output before headers: index.php
```

Comment: Что в логах самого laravel?

Comment: `....218:46566` это же не веб порт.
Можете добавить при каких условиях появилась ошибка?
А так же включить логирование в Laravel и выполнить запрос еще раз, чтобы записать в логи ларавер ошибки. + предоставить нам :)